# I am looking to control an inverter with Raspberry PI

Tags: gpio, python

I am new to Raspberry Pi, and I'm looking for guides or ideas of how I could create a Python program in which I will be able to control the amplitude and the frequency of a rectangular signal, in order to control a Two-phase Motor with the help of a Raspberry Pi v2.

Any hints or ideas are more than welcome! Thank you!

Comment: You cannot control the amplitude without a [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) as the Pi is purely digital.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can blink an LED with PI:

Use optocouplers to prevent backward current and then, give your signal (PWM) to mosfet/igbt driver IC, mostly from Analog Devices or Fairchild.

You will use 2 half bridges for 2 phase.

At the point of amplitude of signal, this is all about your regulator circuit. If you are playing small ranges like 5v to 24v, use an i2c-driven digital potentiometer to regulate input voltage with an adjustable regulator like the LM317.

Comment: Are there any examples that i can check or use for my application?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051) might be helpful if you're new to the Pi and want to learn how to control some type of motor. Don't think it's exactly what you need but it'll get you started turning motors on and off using an IC. You can look into software PWM from there I suppose.